# RN - swiping animated flatlist jamming on swipe when still scrolling

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm having issues with an animated view with a flatlist - [image]

I have a card stack where the card is swipeable but you can also scroll on it.

My swiping panresponder is only turning on for horizontal swipes, however if the scrolling hasn't stopped (due to momentum scroll) and you try and swipe it then the card jams (see gif).

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

```js
export default class Card extends Component {



  componentWillMount() {
    this.pan = new Animated.ValueXY()

    this.cardPanResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => 
      (Math.abs(gestureState.dx) > Math.abs(gestureState.dy)),

      
      onPanResponderMove:
      Animated.event([
        null,
        {dx:this.pan.x, 
        },
      ]),
      onPanResponderRelease: (e, {dx}) => {
        const absDx = Math.abs(dx)
        const direction = absDx / dx
        const swipedRight = direction > 0
        if (absDx > 120) {
          Animated.decay(this.pan, {
            velocity: {x:3 * direction, y:0},
            deceleration: 0.995,
          }).start(()=>this.props.onSwipeOff(swipedRight, this.props.profile.uid))
        } else {
          Animated.spring(this.pan, {
            toValue: {x:0, y:0},
            friction: 4.5,
          }).start()
        }
      },
    })
  }


  render() {
    
    const rotateCard = this.pan.x.interpolate({
      inputRange: [-200, 0, 200],
      outputRange: ['-4deg', '0deg', '4deg'],
    })
    const animatedStyle = {
      transform: [
        {translateX: this.pan.x},
        {rotate: rotateCard},
      ],
    }

    return (
      <Animated.View
        {...this.cardPanResponder.panHandlers}
        style={[animatedStyle]}>
        <View>
          <GridProfile>
        </View>
      </Animated.View>
    )
  }
}
```

Where GridProfile is a component with a flatlist.

Comment: I have seem something similar before when creating a custom picker. Does the application crash completely or does it become responsive again after waiting several minutes?

Comment: @dentemm it doesn't crash, it just jams off center and then it requires you to let go and reswipe the card to bring it back to the center position, where it starts working fine again. It's incredibly frustrating :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is acceptable to wait until momentum scroll has completed, you can use the onScroll handler of the FlatList inside GridProfile.

Edit: updated to disabled scrolling during swipe and disable swiping during scroll. *Disclaimer: untested code! ;-)*

**GridProfile**

Here you need a callback to determine is scrolling is completed (`disableSwipe`), and a prop to disable scrolling when a swipe is detected (`scrollEnabled`).

```js
render() {
  ...
  <FlatList
    scrollEventThrottle={50} // Might need to tweak this 
    onScroll={this.onScroll}
    scrollEnabled={this.props.scrollEnabled}
  />
  ...
}

onScroll = (event) => {

  // if y velocity of onScroll is zero, then scrolling is completed
  if (event.nativeEvent.velocity.y > 0) {
    this.props.setSwipeEnabled(false); 
  } else if (event.nativeEvent.velocity.y === 0) {
    this.props.setSwipeEnabled(true); 
  }
}
```

**Card**

The card component will manage the state for enabling and disabling swipe / scroll

```js
export default class Card extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      swipeEnabled: true,
      scrollEnabled: true  // both of them should initially be possible I assume
    };  
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.pan = new Animated.ValueXY();

    this.cardPanResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder = this.onMoveShouldSetPanResponder,
      onPanResponderGrant = this.onPanResponderGrant,
      onPanResponderMove = this.onPanResponderMove,
      onPanResponderRelease = this.onPanResponderRelease
    })
  }

  render() {

    ...

    return (
      <Animated.View
        {...this.cardPanResponder.panHandlers}
        style={[animatedStyle]}>
        <View>
          <GridProfile
            scrollEnabled={this.state.scrollEnabled}
            setSwipeEnabled={this.setSwipeEnabled}
          >
        </View>
      </Animated.View>
    )
  }

  setSwipeEnabled = (isEnabled) => {
    this.setState({
      swipeEnabled: isEnabled
    });
  }

  onMoveShouldSetPanResponder = (evt, gestureState) => {

    // If swiping is disabled this should return false
    if (!this.state.swipeEnabled) {
      return false;
    }
    return (Math.abs(gestureState.dx) > Math.abs(gestureState.dy))
  }

   onPanResponderGrant = (evt, gestureState) => {
     // disable scrolling when a gesture has been granted
     this.setState({
       scrollEnabled: false
     });
   }

   onPanResponderRelease = (evt, gestureState) => {
     // This might need to be changed to re-enable scrolling to after your animation is finished?
     this.setState({
       scrollEnabled: true
     });
   }
}
```

Comment: The card and swiping actually work fine already when the scrolling has stopped i.e. the list is stationary. The issue is when there is movement (caused by momentum scrolling) and you try and swipe, that's when the card gets stuck off center.

Comment: Yes I understand, but can you also explain you desired behaviour? If scrolling is active when a user swipes, do you want to block that swipe, or do you want to stop scrolling?

Comment: My desired behaviour is that for any vertical initiated gestures then the user can only scroll until the gesture is released. And for any horizontal initiated gestures, the user can only swipe until gesture released.

To achieve this I want to stop scrolling when a user swipes.


The dating app 'bumble' actually has a really great example of this. Their momentum scrolling automatically stops whenever a horizontal gesture is registered.

Comment: I realise my gif is that clear. It requires quite a quick movement to cause this bug, you have to scroll hard enough to get some momentum scrolling and then let go and then try and swipe to cause the issue

Comment: I edited my answer to provide an attempt to a solution

Comment: onScrollEndDrag is indeed only called when the touch gesture ends. I think my solution will work, but as long as momentum scroll is underway swiping left/right will be disabled.

Comment: This may just be the answer! It's not quite the user experience I want as it means users have to wait for the scroll to end, but I'd prefer that to the locking up I'm currently getting. I'll give this a try and let you know how I get on. Maybe another option is to set the scroll offset to the last position registered on OnScroll whenever the swipe gesture is enabled... I'll try both

Comment: You could also increase the decelerationRate prop to minimise momentum duration